# Can I find the list of ports being listened by a process ordered by the time of opening?

Tags: linux, port, netstat, command, lsof

I know I can see the list of open ports using the `lsof` command.

I am trying to view the results ordered by timestamp of listening.

The process opens multiple (~6) ports and I suspect the order of initialization/binding on that port is the cause of a bug. Technically it should be possible to find the relative timestamp of binding by looking at the create timestamp of the fd file created on linux systems.

My query is: is there a command ( netstat or lsof ) which already does that?

P.S: I do not want to go through the route of examining logs because some of these ports are opened by external jars, the init of which is beyond our control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is not (normally) recorded. There is [no available "create time" for a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file), `ctime` is for the file inode/metadata change time. So, after the fact, generally you cannot reliably determine the relative or absolute times.

On any Linux system (2.6.x and 3.x) I've tested, the relevant `/proc` entries are not instantiated until you peek at them, all the timestamps are set to the time the directory is first queried (i.e. these are created on-demand to show the current state, the kernel doesn't needless update these every time any file handle changes). Don't forget these are all *symlinks*, with timestamps independent of the target, and these sockets don't "live" in the filesystem.

```
$ strace -tt -f -e trace=bind,listen /usr/bin/nc -l -p 8080
13:23:23.693432 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr(
                "0.0.0.0")},16) = 0
13:23:23.693542 listen(3, 1)            = 0
```

and in a different terminal a few seconds later:

```
$ date;  ls -cl --full-time /proc/$(pgrep -f "^/usr/bin/nc -l -p 8080")/fd
Mon May 19 13:23:31 IST 2014
total 0
lrwx------ 1 mr users 64 2014-05-19 13:23:31.344141947 +0100 0 -> /dev/pts/206
lrwx------ 1 mr users 64 2014-05-19 13:23:31.344141947 +0100 1 -> /dev/pts/206
lrwx------ 1 mr users 64 2014-05-19 13:23:31.344141947 +0100 2 -> /dev/pts/206
lrwx------ 1 mr users 64 2014-05-19 13:23:31.344141947 +0100 3 -> socket:[206347913]
```

All the symlink times are set 8 seconds later, when `ls` ran.

Note the use of `strace`, this is possibly the simplest way (albeit with a slight performance overhead) to watch the order of the relevant network operations. You might not need or want to use `-f` though, it follows all spawned (child) processes, it can clutter the output (each output line is prefixed with its PID if so).

The next simplest method is likely to use `auditd`/`auditctl` with rules (and careful filtering!) to log the operations, this too has performance implications though (system wide if you're not already running `auditd`, `strace` will only impact the monitored processes).

When you have peers connecting, you can use `netstat` to see the connection details (the `-p` option may be useful as it will show the process), or use `lsof` — though neither will show connection timestamps. To record those connections using `strace`, add `accept` to the list of syscalls in the `trace=` option, and add a `-T` option to time each syscall:  `accept()` will (usually) block, showing only the timestamp it was invoked rather than when it completed. `-T` this will allow you to calculate the completion time.

The extra output for `accept()` looks like:

```
13:25:46.022244 accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(57534), sin_addr=inet_addr(
                "127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 4 <3.167477>
```

showing that the socket was ready to accept connections at 13:25:46, and got its first connection 3.167 seconds later.

Comment: If the jars mentioned by the OP are all spawned by the same process, using `strace -f` on the parent process will also trace any children that are started after the trace was attached.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do most of the trick: `ls --full-time /proc/$PID/fd`

You need to combine that output with the output from `lsof` to know which port number corresponds to which file descriptor.

Update: Turns out the time stamp returned is not the exact time of creation of the file descriptor, but rather the time of the first `ls` of the directory after the file descriptor was created. So to get correct times with the above method, you'll need to run the `ls` command frequently while the sockets are being opened.

Comment: If you `ls -al` it should show you the destination of the fd as well.

Comment: @MKzero Those flags will not help here. `-a` will show directory entries starting with a `.`, but the entries of interest are integers. And `-l` is not needed when `--full-time` is specified. The target of symlinks are shown in the output from the command I suggested. However those targets are just identification numbers used internally by the kernel, translating those identifications to port numbers can only be done by looking at other data structures inside the kernel, lsof can display those other data structures.

Comment: My bad, that's of course true. But to get the lsof line you could use something like `for i in $(ls --full-time /proc/$PID/fd | grep -o -E 'socket:(.*)' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'); do lsof -p $PID | grep -E "$i(.*)LISTEN"; done`

Comment: Have you actually *tested* this?  The timestamps on the first system I had to hand all looked suspiciously similar for every file and socket opened by that process.  Identical down to the nearest microsecond.

Comment: I tested that when opening two sockets several seconds apart, they did in fact get different time stamps. I also found processes where file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 had the same time stamp. I assume the identical time stamps happen when the dup system call is happening.

Comment: @Ladadadada Took a closer look at what those time stamps were. And it looks like what the kernel is actually storing is the time of when you first stat the entry or retrieve a directory listing. Which means if you look at the directory listing frequently enough while opening the various file descriptors, you will see the time stamp from when it was created. But if you only look at the directory listing after the fact, it is not giving the right times. This is really bizarre. So my answer need some updating.